# Find the smallest positive integer x where 149|(x^2-69^3)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$$
\text{Find the smallest positive integer x where 149|}\left( \text{x}^2-69^3 \right) 
$$
I almost do not spot any clue about this question.
It is from PUMaC-CHINA, 2019.8.17

Comment: what clues do you spot.

Comment: $x^2-69^3\equiv x^2+80^3\equiv x^2+36\mod 149$

Comment: I added an answer which uses only a minute of *purely mental arithmetic*. @Roddy Here's a clue:  $ 69\equiv -80\equiv  -5(4^2)\,$ and $\, -5\equiv 12^2$

Comment: 6I was asking the OP bill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This follows the comment by  J. W. Tanner and the answer by sirous.
All congruences are mod $149$.

We have $x^2-69^3 \equiv x^2+36 =x^2+6^2 \equiv (x-6j)(x+6j)$, if $j^2\equiv -1$.

Write $149 = 7^2 + 10^2$. Then $10j \equiv 7$ and so $j\equiv 105$.
Thus $x^2-69^3 \equiv (x-34)(x+34)$ and so $34$ is the smallest positive solution.

Comment: +1; writing $149=7^2+10^2$ was a clever way to solve $j^2\equiv-1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, of course, this works in general for $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

Comment: @J.W.T Actually it's easier to use the obvious $\sqrt{-5}\equiv \sqrt{144}\equiv 12\,$ vs. $\sqrt{-1},\,$ see my answer,

Comment: Note $x^2+6^2 = (10^2+7^2)k$ for some $k$. Put $k=(a^2+b^2)$, then we have $x^2+6^2=(10^2+7^2)(a^2+b^2) = (10a+7b)^2+(10b-7a)^2$ by *Brahmagupta's Identity*. Choose $b=2$ and $a=2$, so that $10b-7a$ becomes equal to $6$, then we get the value of $x$ as $34$ :)

Answer (score 2):

A minute of *mental* arithmetic via $\sqrt{69^{\large 3}}\equiv 69\sqrt{\color{#90f}{69}}\,$ then negating & pulling out more squares

$\!\bmod 149\!:\,\  \color{#90f}{69}\equiv -80\equiv \color{#0a0}{-5}\cdot 4^{\large 2}\equiv \color{#0a0}{144}(4^{\large 2})\equiv \color{#0a0}{12^{\large 2}} 4^{\large 2}\equiv 48^{\large 2} $

${\rm therefore}\ \ \ \ 69\equiv 48^{\large 2}\,\overset{\large \times\, 69^{\Large 2}}\Longrightarrow\,69^{\large 3}\equiv {\underbrace{(69\cdot 48)}_{\large  23\,\cdot\, \underbrace{3\,\cdot\, 48}_{\LARGE {\bf -}5\ \ }}}^{\large 2}\equiv \color{#c00}{34^{\large 2}}$

Comment: Unlike the other answers we show *all* work - it really is a minute of *trivial* mental arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

$69^3=2204 \times 149 +113$

⇒$x^2-69^3 ≡ (x^2-113 )\ mod 149≡ (x^2+36 )\mod 149$

$x^2+36=149 k$

If $k=8$ then:

$x^2=1192 -36=1156=34^2$

⇒ $x= ±34$